# Group condition in last data mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data like this :

```
Table LOT
+-------+--------+
|Lot_id | Prod_id|
+-------+--------+
| LOT-1 | Prd-1  |
| LOT-1 | Prd-2  |
| LOT-1 | Prd-3  |
| LOT-2 | Prd-4  |
+-------+--------+

Table Process
+-------+--------+--------+------------+----------+
|proc_id|proc_cat|proc_seq|proc_prod_id|t_proc_qty|
+-------+--------+--------+------------+----------+
|   1   | Proc-A |   1    |    Prd-1   |   100    |
|   2   | Proc-H |   2    |    Prd-1   |   100    |
|   3   | Proc-D |   3    |    Prd-1   |   100    |
|   4   | Proc-A |   1    |    Prd-2   |   100    |
|   5   | Proc-H |   2    |    Prd-2   |   100    |
|   6   | Proc-D |   3    |    Prd-2   |    20    |
|   7   | Proc-Q |   4    |    Prd-2   |    20    |
|   8   | Proc-A |   1    |    Prd-3   |   100    |
|   9   | Proc-H |   2    |    Prd-3   |   100    |
|  10   | Proc-D |   3    |    Prd-3   |    50    |
|  11   | Proc-O |   1    |    Prd-4   |    80    |
|  12   | Proc-F |   2    |    Prd-4   |    80    |
|  13   | Proc-H |   3    |    Prd-4   |    80    |
+-------+--------+--------+------------+----------+
```

And i want data like this if i want select just LOT=LOT-1.
table LOT joined to table Process and data is accumulated sum(t_proc_qty) from last proc_seq each proc_prod_id and group by proc_cat and order by proc_seq

```
    +--------+--------+----------+
    |proc_cat|proc_seq|t_proc_qty|
    +--------+--------+----------+
    | Proc-D |   3    |   150    |->accumulated from Prd-1 and prd-3 in last process is seq 3
    | Proc-Q |   4    |    20    |->accumulated from Prd-2 in last process is seq 4
    +--------+--------+----------+
```

What queries I use in MySQL ?

I stucked in query

```
SELECT proc_cat, proc_seq, SUM(t_proc_qty) 
FROM Process 
LEFT JOIN Lot ON proc_prod_id=Prod_id 
WHERE Lot_id='LOT-1' 
GROUP BY proc_prod_id 
ORDER BY proc_seq DESC LIMIT 1
```

this schema for trial query [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1fa3fd)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show us efforts you did till now.

Comment: I stucked in query
SELECT proc_cat, proc_seq, SUM(t_proc_qty)
FROM Process
LEFT JOIN Lot ON proc_prod_id=Prod_id
GROUP BY proc_prod_id
ORDER BY proc_seq DESC
LIMIT 1

Comment: Edit your question accordingly

Comment: Why is Prd-2 not considered in your desired result?

Comment: maybe you are referring to is a lot-2?

Comment: Here is your query explained: You outer join table `Lot`. That makes no sense, as you are only interested in matches. So use an inner join instead. Your `where` clause does that implicitly anyway by the way, because in an outer-joined record `lot_id` is null. Then you aggregate the records per `proc_prod_id`. You are using no aggregate function on `proc_seq` and `proc_cat` however, so the DBMS simply picks one of the `proc_seq` and `proc_cat` per `proc_prod_id` arbitrarily. At last you limit your results to one row, based on that randomly picked `proc_seq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From table `Process` you want the records with the highest `proc_id` per `proc_prod_id`:

```
select *
from process
where not exists 
(
  select * 
  from process later 
  where later.proc_prod_id = process.proc_prod_id
  and later.proc_id > process.proc_id
);
```

From this data you want an aggregate per `proc_cat` and `proc_sec`. And you also want to consider only `prod_id` for 'LOT-1' in table `LOT`.

The complete query:

```
select proc_cat, proc_seq, sum(t_proc_qty)
from process
where proc_prod_id in (select prod_id from lot where lot_id = 'LOT-1')
and not exists 
(
  select * 
  from process later 
  where later.proc_prod_id = process.proc_prod_id
  and later.proc_id > process.proc_id
)
group by proc_cat, proc_seq
order by proc_cat, proc_seq;
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1fa3fd/5

Comment: This query works like a charm, thx..
it can use join condition instead of sub select  ?

Comment: in result query above shown 2 row data i want to combine with count. so result query just show 1 row with value is count of data:
+-------+
|count |
+-------+

Comment: Yes, you can join instead of using an `IN` clause. Many do so. I prefer the `IN`  clause (or an `EXISTS` clause sometimes), because they make it clear what you are doing (i.e. look at records in table `process` that have a match **in** `lot`, in other words records in table `process` for which **exists** a match in `lot`). Such criteria belongs in the `where` clause in my opinion, which becomes more important even, when there may be duplicate matches.

Comment: I don't understand your other request. If you want one row, then don't group by `proc_cat` and `proc_seq`, but only show `sum(t_proc_qty)` over all records. Is that what you want?

Comment: Oh, and if you were not referring to the `IN` subquery, but the `EXISTS` subquery: Yes, you could join instead, but that would be with the `max(prod_id)` per `proc_prod_id`, which would still be a subquery, only in your `from` clause, instead of your `where` clause.